# Index of minimum, excluding negative values

Tags: matlab, performance, indexing, minimum

I want to find the index of min element in array `L`, but negative numbers should be ignored. Is there a simpler way than this?

```
L = xB./a_i;
for j = 1:length(L)
    if L(j) < 0
        L(j) = Inf;
    end
end
[~, indOut] = min(L);
```

Comment: Do you really need the `Inf` values in that array, or was this just done in order to try and find the minimum?

Comment: @Dev-iL It was just done to find the minimum of positive elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:

You can do this in a fairly simple one liner using the same logic

```
[~, indOut] = min( abs(L)./(L>=0) );
```

The logic here:

```
abs(L) % Positive (absolute) values of L
./     % Element-wise divide. Note that x/0 = Inf for x>0
L>=0   % Logical array; 0 when L<0 

% So: Elements where L<0 are divided by 0, and become Inf. 
%     Positive value is the one being divided, so never -Inf

%     Elements where L>=0 are divided by 1, remain unchanged
%     These elements are already positive, so abs(L) == L here.
```

---

Either way, you don't need the loop

```
L( L < 0 ) = Inf;
[~, indOut] = min( L );
```

---

Note that, if you didn't want the index (but just the minimum value), you could do this

```
m = min( L( L >= 0 ) );
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `(L<0)*NaN` (or for that matter, _anything_ multiplied by `NaN`) is `NaN` everywhere. Perhaps you meant `min( L./(L>=0) )`?

Comment: @Dev-iL Agh you're right, I didn't have MATLAB open so I was shooting from the hip. Edited.

Comment: Hmm. I appear to have misled you, since `L./(L>=0)` produces `-Inf` for negative values, which doesn't help here. `L .* (L>=0) ./ (L>=0)` works though. Sorry about that :(

Comment: @Dev-iL `abs(L)./(L>=0)` is a bit neater / clearer and should achieve the same thing - I think? Although in the end I fear probs slower and more convoluted than the original solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. in your other solution what happens to division in `abs(L)./(L>=0)` when L element is negative? does it mean divide by 1 if positive and divide by 0 if negative?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I've added some explanation to my answer, essentially you're correct.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution, in case you don’t want to modify `L`, is to first find the minimum value, and then find its index in a second step:

```
minL = min(L(L>=0));
index = find(L==minL,1);
```

Normally it is bad to use equality comparisons with floating-point numbers, but in this case `minL` must be exactly identical to at least one element in `L`, so the comparison cannot fail.

Comment: Cannot fail? I'm not sure about the intricacies of how MATLAB stores FP data, but surely there's a chance that `minL` and the original element of `L` could differ by `eps` because they're stored separately? Is there a low-level guarantee that they're the same? (I nearly suggested this method myself, just curious!)

Comment: @Wolfie: floats can differ by eps if computed in equivalent but not identical ways. In this case, the value from the matrix is just copied over, there is no reason for the bit pattern to change. I don’t know if there is some guarantee explicitly written anywhere, but it would be weird if `min` returned a value that is not the actual minimum of the matrix, but only approximates it. Especially since both the obvious method and the most efficient known method to determine the min return an identical copy of the value.

Comment: makes sense, I've got confidence in the method - just extending the thought you already spared it :)